# What's the best budget macro lens option for micro 4/3 Panasonic Lumix gf3?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, macro, micro-four-thirds

I would like to get into macro photography.. Just wondering what the best macro lens would be in the $150-200 price range? I would like to get the Panasonic/Leica macro lens but not in the budget. Btw my camera is the Panasonic Lumix gf3.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you recommend a macro lens for a micro 4/3 camera?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8303/can-you-recommend-a-macro-lens-for-a-micro-4-3-camera)

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered extension tubes? Take a look at the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_tube) they're a lot cheaper and if you're just starting out in macro photograph are often a beeter way to get started.

Comment: I settled on the Raynox dcr 250 it's a not a dedicated macro lens.. But it has some of the best reviews I've seen and the results are fantastic