# Will the Raynox DCR 250 Macro + GF3 kit lens provide good results? 

Tags: macro, raynox, macro-converter

I have a Panasonic Lumix GF3 with the stock 14-42 lens. I've been away from photography for some time now. I bought a Raynox DRC 250 macro and was wondering if I would achieve pretty good results with the stock GF3 lens or do I need a telephoto-style lens to get decent macro shots?

Answer (score 1):

With a macro converter like the DCR 250 you are going to be trying to balance between getting a workable depth of field (creatively interesting, but challenging) with longer lenses, and getting rid of vignetting when shooting wide.

I've found similar setups require a lot of care in setting up, but your stock lens should, especially when racked out, be able capable of capturing solid images.

Here are a few examples of images taken (not by myself) with similar setup to yours (all at 42mm) to give you an idea of what is possible:

http://www.flickr.com/photos/floydevansclan/6226432626/

http://www.flickr.com/photos/floydevansclan/6182453948/

Comment: Wow! Great pictures! I'm definitely getting one of these for my GX1. Where these pictures taken using the kit 14-42mm you say?

Comment: They aren't my images, but based on the EXIF data, and another note by the photographer, yes - they are both shot at 42mm f/5.6 with the kit lens.